# What is the negation of a closed subset?

Tags: general-topology, definition

Closed subset:= If $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges and the elements of the sequence are all in $A$ then the Limit sits in $A$.

If I could Show that there **exists** a convergent sequence where all the Elements of the sequence are in $A$ and the Limit is not in $A$ would it be equivalent to say that $A$ is not a closed subset?$(*)$

I.e $A$ not a closed subset $\iff \exists (a_n)_n\in\mathbb{N},a_n\in A \forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergent and $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\notin A$

I have the Feeling that something is wrong because the Definition says:

$A$  closed subset $\iff \forall(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},a_n\in A \forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}} convergent\Rightarrow lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\in A$

Therefor the Negation would have to be

$A$ not closed subset $\iff \forall(a_n)_n\in\mathbb{N},a_n\in A \forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergent and $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\notin A$

If I have $(*)$ can it help me to prove:

$A$ closed subset $\iff A^C$ is open

Comment: Yes, it should be **exists**, as you describe at the beginning of your post. The negation at the end of your post is incorrect.

Comment: The negation of $\forall$ is $\exists$.

Comment: but $\neg (A\Rightarrow B )= A$ and $\neg B$ with $A$ being:$\forall(a_n)_n\in\mathbb{N},a_n\in A \forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$convergent and $B$ being $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\in A$

Comment: You said I have to Change the quantorsign but the Formula above says that A must remain as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define closed as sequentially closed (so every sequence in $A$ that converges in $X$ to $p$ has $ p \in A$ too), then the logical negation of that

$A$ is not closed iff there *exists* some sequence $(a_n)$ converging to $p$ where all $a_n \in A$ but $p \notin A$. (so one such sequence is enough to disprove closedness).

I don't see how that helps you proving $A$ closed iff its complement is open if you don't also have a definition of open sets in terms of sequences.

A final word of caution: said equivalence of closed and sequentially closed does not holds in all spaces (but it does in e.g. metric spaces, a very common case).